# Procedure - Dynamic where conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I have a procedure, based on the parameters, the where condition would differ.
The OUT parameters have to be INTO clause so that I can return the columns from the procedure.

Rather than having SQL condition for each if condition, what is the efficient way of doing this.

Comment: Maybe GurV meant to post some of the different queries, not only one

Comment: @GurV I have not included all my IN parameters, there are around 10 IN parameters. So there will be more where conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me more like a design question. 
So it depends on what you need to achieve and how you want to organize your code.

Possibilities

1- your "if" chain of queries in the same procedure

2- one procedure for each query

3 - if the differencies between the "where" parts are not so big use sql constructs, including unions, case , and\or etc to let coexist different cases in one query

4- build sql dynamically and use execute immediate

Usually i don't like the 1, i would try with 3 or 4, then proceed with 2 if i can't.

EDIT

With dynamic sql, for getting out results you can do

```
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt into o_total_count,o_total_sum,o_hold_status,o_normal_status;
```

In case you have input params for the query, you have to mark them with : and then add the USING clause with the appropriate input param.

Example

```
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select count(*) from departments where department_id=:id' INTO l_cnt USING l_dept_id;
```

Comment: If I am using EXCUTE IMMEDIATE, how do I assign the values to OUT parameters.

Comment: EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt INTO var1,var2;

Comment: See my edit in the answer for additional explanations on dynamic sql

Comment: Thanks, much appreicated.